# How to categorise UI/UX notes?

Tags: learning, education

I would like to start taking down notes on UI/UX but I do not know how to categorise them. Take UI for example, there are so many UI elements. And should I separate UI from UX? But then again, it is hard to draw a line between them.

I would like to have this sort out before taking down my notes so that I won't need to spend time arranging them next time.

Please share with me any suggestions or advice you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: There are many options. It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Choose what works best for you**

---

Since you specifically mentioned UI and UX, two possible use cases immediately came to my mind:

- Heuristic evaluation
- Design system/Styleguide

#### Heuristic Evaluation

In a [Heuristic Evaluation](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/how-to-conduct-a-heuristic-evaluation/), you analyse the UI based on a set of usability guidelines. You could use [Nielsen's heuristics](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) or find others that are more suitable for your purposes. You could even come up with your own heuristics.

In case of a heuristic evaluation, you would likely organize your notes per page/screen and could categorize them by:

- violated heuristic(s)
- severity rating

Additionally, you should also add an explanation of the violation and suggestions for improvement. You could use one of the many templates you can find on the internet ([like this excel-sheet](https://www.uxforthemasses.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Usability-review-template.xls)), but make sure that it suits your purpose.

#### Design system / Styleguide

A [Design system](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/design-systems-101/) is used as a common set of standards that you, your fellow designers, developers etc. can refer to. It can help to avoid inconsistencies and reduce redundant design discussions/decisions, by having a clear specification of all your (UI) buildings blocks.

You would likely organize your design system by UI elements. Categories could be (but are certainly not limited to):

- Buttons
- Form fields
- Typography
- Colors
- ...

#### Else

There are several other methods in the UX process and many of them come with their specific strategy of note taking and organizing. Another one I would like to point out is an [Affinity diagram](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/affinity-diagram/). This might not apply to your situation because it is less tied to specific UI-elements, but a neat way to organize and prioritize UX findings from qualitative studies (e.g. interviews) or unstructured ideas.

#### In conclusion

There is no "golden rule" of what is best. Consider your situation and make sure you know what you want/need. Then figure out what works best for you to achieve that goal. And don't be afraid to adapt common practices or even invent a new approach. After all, there is no "one size fits all" in life.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your suggestion. I really appreciate you taking your time out to type this out for me. 

I think categorising my UX notes based on heuristic evaluation sounds like a feasible way, maybe i'll try just that!

Comment: You're welcome! Please let me know if you have further questions and feel free to upvote and/or accept this answer if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some standardish names for bits of a website or software, I resorted to using an appendix with annotated screenshots of screens with made up logical names for the bits of the screen (side menu; top menu etc).  This meant that anyone reading the report later had a visual guide to the names of bits of screen I was referring to.

Comment: Hi PhillipW, thank you for your suggestion. So something like a log where you record all the notes that you've taken down and just give them headers/tags? 

If you don't mind, could you kindly share a visual about it? Thanks again!